# azure/msal: invalid_grant: AADB2C90080: The provided grant has expired

Tags: reactjs, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

We are using azure/msal-node with ADB2C Custom policies.
Sometimes we face the following issue: a user clicks signIn link in the SPA, that link generates an endpoint which should show the credentials form: https://[tenant].b2clogin.com/[tenant].onmicrosoft.com/b2c_1a_signin/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?…
But the page is not opened, and user is redirected back. In the logs we see:

```
ServerError: invalid_grant: undefined - [undefined]: AADB2C90080: The provided grant has expired. Please re-authenticate and try again. Current time: 1686924780, Grant issued time: 1686921381, Grant expiration time: 1686921972
```

That happens after about 24h of inactivity.

Before a user tries to open the for we try to refresh his token in the background via acquireTokenSilent(). Which returns null.

Any help to resolve this is appreciated , Thanks in advance.